# Login page content not showing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, laravel-5.3

I tried a lot to show the login page contents but due to some reasons it does not show. Am I missing something in below code?

**App.Js**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "ngCookies"]);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
                                             function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl     :   "App/Templates/Auth/Login.html",
            controller      :   "LoginController",
            authenticated   :   false
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise("/");
    }
]);
```

**Login Controller**

```
myApp.controller("LoginController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

}]);
```

**Login.html**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="LoginController">
   This is login page
</div>
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('App/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js')}}"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js')}}"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js')}}"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/App.js')}}"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.js')}}"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Server Route**

```
Route::get('/', function() {
        return View::make('master');
    }
);
```

Comment: do you see any errors in console?

Comment: No errors coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master.blade.php files should be referenced like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js')}}"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('App/App.js')}}"></script>
```